# JSON Configuration for Serilog.Exception destructurers

Tags: c#, exception, serilog, asp.net-core-2.2, serilog-exceptions

I am adding Serilog to the project and I specifically want to add `Serilog.Exceptions` as well. Following the [guideline](https://github.com/RehanSaeed/Serilog.Exceptions) I've added just the Exceptions enricher successfully, but I also need the destructures mentioned in the linked page.

The following works fine using fluent configuration:

```
config.Enrich.WithExceptionDetails(new DestructuringOptionsBuilder()
    .WithDefaultDestructurers()
    .WithDestructurers(new ExceptionDestructurer[]
    {
        new DbUpdateExceptionDestructurer(),
        new SqlExceptionDestructurer()
    }));
```

However, I'm struggling to get it configured using JSON config like this:

```
config.ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration);
```

Here's what I've tried already without much luck:

```
"Enrich": [
      { "Name": "FromLogContext" },
      {
        "Name": "WithExceptionDetails",
        "Args": {
          "With": "DbUpdateException, SqlException"
        }
      } 
]
```

and also:

```
"Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithExceptionDetails" ],
"Destructure": [
      {
        "Name": "With",
        "Args": { "policy": "DbUpdateException, SqlException" }
      }
]
```

How do I configure the fluent version using JSON?

Comment: It seems it is impossible to configure `Destructure` from Configuration, try to refer [Add support for serilog-settings-configuration #58](https://github.com/RehanSaeed/Serilog.Exceptions/issues/58)

Comment: @TaoZhou, thanks for the link. Yeah I resorted to configure it using code as well. You can post an answer if you want, so this question can be actually closed

Comment: Since version 3.0.0 of https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration there is now support for Destructure from config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, it is not supported to configure `Destructure` from Configuration which is by design.

It is recommended to configure through code.

Reference : [Add support for serilog-settings-configuration #58](https://github.com/RehanSaeed/Serilog.Exceptions/issues/58)