# How to configure Serilog.Exceptions.SqlServer in appsettings.json

Tags: serilog, serilog-exceptions

I'm using appsettings.json to configure Serilog. I added `Serilog.Exceptions`, which works like a charm.

```
"Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Settings.Configuration", "Serilog.Exceptions" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
        "Default": "Information",
        "Override": {
            "Microsoft": "Warning",
            "System": "Warning"
        }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
        { "Name": "Console" },
        {
            "Name": "File",
            "Args": {
                "path": "%TEMP%\\Logs\\serilog-configuration-sample.txt",
                "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception} {Properties:j}",
                "rollingInterval": "Day"
            }
        }
    ],
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithThreadId", "WithExceptionDetails" ]
}
```

But since I'm using Sql Server and EF Core, the [documentation](https://github.com/RehanSaeed/Serilog.Exceptions#serilogexceptionssqlserver) says I also have to configure `Serilog.Exceptions.SqlServer` and `Serilog.Exceptions.EntityFrameworkCore`.

According to this documentation this has to be added to the enrichter. In C# code this would be:

```
.Enrich.WithExceptionDetails(new DestructuringOptionsBuilder()
    .WithDefaultDestructurers()
    .WithDestructurers(new[] { new SqlExceptionDestructurer() }))
```

I can't figure out how to do that in `appsettings.json`. Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible at the moment, although the author is open for a PR if someone implements it.

See [this issue](https://github.com/RehanSaeed/Serilog.Exceptions/issues/300), [this discussion](https://github.com/RehanSaeed/Serilog.Exceptions/issues/58) and [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58587661/json-configuration-for-serilog-exception-destructurers).